# Apache Zeppelin: interpreter.json keeps getting reset

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to change the default interpreter in an interpreter group.

Specifically, I'm changing

```
"defaultInterpreter": true,
```

to

```
"defaultInterpreter": false,
```

in

```
{
  "name": "spark",
  "class": "org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter",
  "defaultInterpreter": true,
  "editor": {
    "language": "scala",
    "editOnDblClick": false,
    "completionKey": "TAB",
    "completionSupport": true
  }
},
```

Then changing the next section (Spark SQL) to true.

But then as I restart Zeppelin, interpreter.json gets reverted.

Please advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok after digging around I think I found the right place.

In interpreters/< interpreter >/interpreter-settings.json is the actual place to edit the settings.

conf/interpreter.json is generated.

I wish these things were easily found in docs or via search though, not by developers digging and trying different things.